# google map JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 42 of the JSON data

Tags: json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, json-deserialization

I have string which was stringified from google map object.

the string: [{"type":"polygon","path":"kryA}iejSZYJ\I^"}]

When trying to parse this string back to object using JSON.parse, I've got the error

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad escaped character at line 1 column 42 of the JSON data
```

my code was

```
JSON.parse('[{"type":"polygon","path":"kryA}iejSZYJ\\I^"}]')
```

So what is wrong here? Did google produce a bad code that when stringified, it can not go back to object again?

Comment: which library you are using to serialize to json? Library will automatically add escape character wherever needed.

Comment: I just JSON.stringigy(object);

Comment: oh, so you want array of object instead of object. so in this case you can do like this `var array = [ object ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are not properly encoding json. BTW if you try like this

```
 var obj =  [{"type":"polygon","path":"kry`A}iejSZYJ\\I^"}]
```

then it will work

Comment: the difference is the extra \ character

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `\\`
You can use the direct input from google

```
[Object { type="polygon", path="aqyAmiejSc@[MJ^\"}]
```

You have to  use  either

`JSON.parse('[{"type":"polygon","path":"kry`A}iejSZYJ\I^"}]')`

or

```
JSON.parse('[{"type":"polygon","path":"kry`A}iejSZYJ\\\\I^"}]')
```

or

```
JSON.parse('[{"type":"polygon","path":"kry`A}iejSZYJ\\\\\\\\I^"}]')
```